# mysql condition to validate data based on certain condtion

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables,namely `booking` and `ledger`.

`booking` table:

```
BookingID -- RegularPrice -- DownPayment  -- PerMonthInstallment
   1            100,000         10,000          7,500
```

`ledger` table:

```
BookingID  Voucher  -- PaymentType  -- Amount
1             1        Down Payment    10,000
1             2        Installment     7,500
```

Current output is;

```
PaymentType --  PerMonthInstallment -- PaidAmount
Down Payment        7,500                 7,500
Installment#1       7,500                 7,500
```

What i want is, if `PaymentType` is Down Payment then in the `PerMonthInstallment` column, the value should be `10,000` rather than `7,500`.

```
PaymentType --    PermonthInstallment --    PaidAmount
Down Payment        10,000                   10,000
Installment#1       7,500                     7,500
```

My Query:

```
SELECT booking.BookingID,  
       booking.PerMonthInstallment, 
       ledger.PaymentType,
       ledger.PaidAmount,
       ledger.Voucher
from booking
INNER JOIN ledger ON booking.BookingID = ledger.BookingID
```

Comment: That's confusing. In your description you talk about a column `DueAmount` yet such a column is neither in your samples nor in your query. And instead of describing the logic you use values (7500, 10000), which leaves further room for (mis)interpretation. You should elaborate.

Answer (score 0):

oK now, my first suggestion is you shouldn't use payment type using words. what you can do is you can give a number as an example let's say 
**downpayment =1 
  installment =2** 
so when you're using them you can put condition from them 
for your query question you can use IF

```
SELECT IF(PaymentType=='Down Payment',10000,7500) AS Dueamount FROM TableName;
```

if you're changing to my suggestion

```
   SELECT IF(PaymentType==1,10000,7500) AS Dueamount FROM TableName;
```

the reason is let's say there is going to be extra space in somewhere but you can't see it still program considering those spaces it will take some time to notice that space so use number instead of this and this is database anomaly